# submit of form using type button javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have a form with an element of type button. I want to use the onclick method to set an image of an img tag, and then simulate the "action" of the form. I tried the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function imgtest(){
document.getElementById

("test").src="progress.gif";

}
</script>


<title>Hello</title>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
<input type="button" value="Submit" 

onclick="imgtest()">
</form>
<div id="img">
<img id="test" src="load.png">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Though, this does not seem to work. What may be the other solution?

Comment: Why not change the image on the form's onSubmit event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `type="submit"` controls do submit their form automatically, `type="button"`s do not. You can trigger the submission with JavaScript by executing

```
this.form.submit();
```

at the end of the click event handler of the button (that is inside the form).

**There is no need to use jQuery or to give an ID to the form**, as form controls always refer back to their form.

Answer (score 4):

you can do it like this

give an id to your form

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php" id="someid">
```

on button click method in  jquery

```
$('#buttonid').click(
function(){
 $("#someid").submit();
  });
```

use `document.getElementById('formidhere').submit();` //for javascript solution

Comment: There is no jQuery in his source? But I was not the dowvoter :)

Comment: @zladuric that's why i have also written the java script solution

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript

```
document.getElementById('form').submit();
```

In JQuery

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

First give the id to your form

ex.

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php" id="testForm">
```

then in you button click event write as below in your **imgtest()** function :

```
document.getElementById('testForm').submit();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function imgtest(){
document.getElementById("test").src="progress.gif";
var frm=document.getElementById("frm1");
frm.submit();


}
```